# Figure number is missing in cleveref

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subfloats, subcaption, subfig

**Figure number is missing in subcaption references, when using cleveref. How can I get a subcaption reference as Fig.1(a), instead of Fig. (a)?**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\RequirePackage{figureSeries}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=false,hypertexnames=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalise]{cleveref}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\newcommand{\csubfloat}[2][]{\makebox[0pt]{\subfloat[#1]{#2}}}


% % packages for this example
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
      % Subfigure A
         \hspace*{\fill}%
            \csubfloat[First subcaption.]
            {\label{fig:Figure1a}%
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}
         \hspace*{\fill}
      % Subfigure B
         \hspace*{\fill}
            \csubfloat[Second subcaption.]
            {\label{fig:Figure1b}%
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}}
         \hspace*{\fill}
      % Overall caption and label
         \caption{Overall caption of the Figure.}
         \label{fig:Figure1}
\end{figure}

Current reference to Figure 1a typesets as \textbf{\cref{fig:Figure1a}}.
\\
Current reference to Figure 1b typesets as \textbf{\cref{fig:Figure1b}}. 
\\ \\
\textbf{Why don't I get something like this?} {\color{red}\textbf{Fig.1(a)}} \textbf{and} {\color{red} \textbf{Fig.1(b)}} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know the `subcaption` package? I think you should give it a try, because it allows you to set/get references of subfigures (and subtables).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, as @P.M. just wrote, the `\usepackage{subcaption}` was part of the solution :)

Comment: `\usepackage{subcaption}` is part of the `figureSeries` package. The solution is to revert the settings change of the `figureSeries` package with `\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example document could be boiled down to:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% from figureSeries.sty
% (taken from https://github.com/thomasWeise/figureSeries)
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{figure}

% from your document
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\subfloat[Test\label{fig:1a}]{This is not an image}
\caption{Some text\ldots}
\end{figure}
\ref{fig:1a} % typesets "(a)"
\end{document}
```

What happens here: The `figureSeries` package uses `\DeclareCaptionSubType*` to make the figure counter part of the sub-figure counter. And with `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}` you remove the figure-part of the sub-figure labeling, but `\label` resp. `\ref` is not aware of your re-definition (and therefore does not prepend the figure counter since it assumes that it is already part of the sub-figure counter), and as result you have eliminated the figure-part completely.

What could be done instead: If you don't like the sub-figure setup of the `figureSeries` package, reverse this setting with `\DeclareCaptionSubType` (without star), for example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% from figureSeries.sty
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{figure}

% from your document
\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure} % revert setting of figureSeries.sty
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\subfloat[Test\label{fig:1a}]{This is not an image}
\caption{Some text\ldots}
\end{figure}
\ref{fig:1a} % typesets "1(a)"
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and for the solution!!!
I think I got confused with the `figureSeries` package...!

I Just commented `% \RequirePackage{figureSeries}` and I added
`\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure}`

Comment: If you don't use the `figureSeries` package anymore the line `\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure}` could be dropped since this is the default setting. (But it does not make any harm, so you could keep it, too.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should study the packages more carefully!